# Dynamic SUMIF based on string contents

Tags: excel

I'm sure this has been done before, but I wasn't sure how to formulate the question without giving an example.  I would like to create a part number/price generator.  I have each option in a row with a price, and then I would like the sum of the various options if the part number string contains the specified option.

For example:

```
A   $10
B   $20
C   $30
D   $40
```

The formula should return the sum of the options based on the input string.  (note the dash is a part number delimiter, not a "minus") ie:

```
A        $10  
A-B      $30
A-B-C-D  $100
```

I've used SUMIF before, but not sure how to get it to sum multiple columns on the contents of a specific cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your first table (data) is on A3:B6 and the second on A8:B10 (results), the formula to place on cell B8 would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$3:A$6;A8))*B$3:B$6)
```

Note: For this solution to work, the dash separated value cannot contain each other, i.e., you cannot have something like "A-AB-B-BC-C".

Comment: Thanks!  This worked well, with a minor change (comma in the search rather than semicolon):  
    =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$3:A$6,A8))*B$3:B$6)  
  
I was also able to achieve the result with a helper column to do a TRUE/FALSE if the row text exists in the "part number" and then a sumif the row has the true/false, but this is a much easier, one-step solution!

Comment: In Portugal comma is the decimal separator. To separate function parâmetros we use the semicolon.